# how to implement arithmetic operator for boost::variant so that it supports different numeric types

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

For example, if I have the following variant and a static_visitor:

```
typedef boost::variant<long, int, float, double> DataType;
```

And I'd like this to work:

```
DataType x(1.2);
DataType y(100);
std::cout<<boost::apply_visitor(Multiply(), x, y)<<std::endl; // should return 120
```

with a visitor like this:

```
struct Multiply : public boost::static_visitor<DataType>
{
    template<typename T, typename U>
    DataType operator()(const T& a, const U& b) const
    {
        // what to do here??
    }

    template<typename T>
    DataType operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const
    {
        return a * b;
    }
};
```

How I can do this without having to list all the possible combinations of types in the Multiply visitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice: Don't special-case on same type, but on multiplyability:

```
struct Multiply : public boost::static_visitor<DataType> {
    template<typename T, typename U>
    static auto operator()(const T& a, const U& b) const
    -> decltype(DataType(a*b)){
        return a*b;
    }
    template<typename... Ts>
    static DataType operator()(const Ts... params) const {
        throw std::invalid_argument("can't multiply");
    }
};
```

Changes:

- No special-casing of any combination which works.
- Throwing an exception on any combination which does not.
- Now `static`.

Uses expression-SFINAE to decide.

Still, it won't return 120 for your example, because binary floating-point cannot represent 1.2 exactly.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but what does the 2nd operator() in your example do?

Comment: The second operator is selected when the first one is discarded by SFINAE. And it just throws a runtime-exception.

Comment: I see, but I think the example you give doesn't work out of the box, I got errors like this: call of ‘(const Multiply) (long int&, double&)’ is ambiguous. However I can make it work by change the 2nd operator to a variadic template. Can I edit your answer to correct it?